# Coffee script code for file size validation in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I had tried to **validate the file size** for attachments in nested attributes. But it is not working properly. Anyone faced the similar problem?

Comment: Hello Welcome to Stack overflow , Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). And please post [minimal reproducile](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field count size is just in case you have multiple file attachments. You first have to check the file size for the files that are not hidden and then add error message to it.

```
$('.file-submit-button').click ->
    fields_count = 0
    $('.file-attachment').each ->
      fields_count++

      if this.files[0].size > 5 * 1000 * 1000 && $(this).closest('div[class=fields]').css('display') != 'none'
        file_attachment_fields = document.querySelectorAll('.file-attachment')
        file_attachment_fields[fields_count - 1].setCustomValidity('File size exceeds 5 MB')
        file_attachment_fields[fields_count - 1].reportValidity()
      else
        file_attachment_fields = document.querySelectorAll('.file-attachment')
        file_attachment_fields[fields_count - 1].setCustomValidity('')
```